# Autohide div error on right-click

Tags: jquery, animation, onclick

Am using jquery to show a div on click and to hide it when you click anywhere else! But the problem is, the script also hides the div when you right click INSIDE the div.

here is my jquery;

```
$(function() {
    $(".activities a").click(function(e) {
        $('.search').html('<center><img src="loading.gif" style="margin: 20px 0;" /></center>');
        $(".search").toggle().toggleClass("active");
        $('.search').load('someurlhere.php');
        e.stopPropagation();
    });


    $(document).click(function(e) {
        $('.active').hide().removeClass('active');
    });

    $(".search").click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try:

```
$(document).click(function(e) {

    // only hide div if something else other than
    // the .active div or one of its children is clicked
    if(!$(e.target).hasClass("active") && !$(e.target).closest(".active").length) {
        $('.active').hide().removeClass('active');
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/karim79/8bUgc/